# Connect button to GPIO without breadboard?

Tags: gpio, breadboard

Is there a way to connect a button to a Raspberry Pi 3B+ without a breadboard? If so, how? Could you give a diagram and explain? I am only a beginner so please make it easy to understand. Also I would like to avoid soldering. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Multicolored-Breadboard-Dupont-Jumper-Wires/dp/B073X7P6N2/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1544471573&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=electronics+jumper+wires&psc=1    The female ends on those wires will slip onto the headers of your pi, then you would just need a switch that also has small posts to connect the other wire to. Of course without soldering, they are likely to not be a great connection.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with the female to male jumper wires and some alligator clips, but why would you want to go that much trouble to avoid soldering or a breadboard?

For a diagram, wire it exactly like the [diagram in this picture](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#button), but skip the breadboard and wire directly from GP2 to one side of your switch and from the other side of your switch to a GND pin.